# How to get Java XP Look and Feel

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

I want to give XP Look and Feel to my Java Desktop Appliction, regardless of the platform it will run.

I came to know that since JDK 1.4, Sun Microsystems has officially released a look and feel for XP - `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel`

I am using Java 1.6 but when I didn't find any package named `windows` in `javax.swing.plaf` package.

Q1. How can I use the XP Look and Feel?

Q2. Will using this look and feel will appear same on all platforms (mac, solaris, linux)?

Comment: You will need to "roll-your-own"

Answer (score 10):

You can't. The XP look and feel, along with several of the other platform-flavoured look-and-feels, depends on native support from the actual platform. It can only be used on XP.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [JGoodies Library](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/looks/)

It provides several Swing Look&Feel Styles that do not look exactly like the Windows Design but come close and sure look better that the typical Swing style.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the danger of "look and feel" law suites, the Window PL&F is only available on Windows and it checks the `os.name` system property to make sure..

It used to run on Linux okay. For XP it needs to look up skin information which wouldn't be present (same as the Gtk PL&F). And you probably shouldn't distribute this sort of thing.

Comment: Does it also depend on native support as claimed by SamB, or is this simply a case of ducking a lawsuit?  I would have thought, being Swing that it didn't depend on the native windowing widgets at all.

Comment: Actually for XP, and presumably Vista there is (or was) no skin information. It runs (not tried it recently) run 95 and classic PL&F okay.